# MySQL and PHP escape back slash

Tags: php, mysql

I have an constant that is a string that contains a back slash `\`.

The problem is, MySQL seems to escape this character which is not the behavior expected.

Here is the code:

```
const METHOD_TYPE_CREDITCARD = "Braintree\CreditCard";

$sql = "SELECT transaction_id AS id,  
  CASE
    WHEN source_type = '0' THEN '".PaymentGateway::METHOD_TYPE_CREDITCARD."'
  END AS source 
FROM transactions WHERE invoice_id = :id"
```

It sure runs the query properly but escapes the `\`. So the output looks like:

```
[id] => myx0kpe8
[source] => BraintreeCreditCard
```

I tried what @strawberry mentioned. Still the same results with

```
const METHOD_TYPE_CREDITCARD = "Braintree\\CreditCard";
```

Comment: That's a backslash. \\ would escape it, as would any number of well-documented methods

Comment: @Strawberry yes sure I can escape it with \\ will escape it in PHP but MySQL still seems to escape it and print `BraintreeCreditCard`

Comment: Use parameters from `pdo` or `mysqli`

Comment: Have you tried more slashes? like `\\\\ ` First pair escapes it in PHP so puts the literal ` \ ` in the string and the second pair escapes it for MySQL. Using `mysql_real_escape_string` is your other option

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Good idea. Let me give it a try

Comment: Always use parameters because of security @user3284463. Every other thing is insane in these days. Keyword: Sql Injection

Comment: 2  should  um *should* be enough, but sometimies you jus gotta  \\\

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It seems to be working :). Please post an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt you 're right about prepared statements but this is a constant not **user input**. It's safe IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done, is a self made SQL Injection.

As already commented, you should use parameters in form of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (PDO or the equvivalent in `mysqli`) instead of string concatenation.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT transaction_id AS id,  
  CASE
    WHEN source_type = '0' THEN ':creditcard'
  END AS source 
FROM transactions WHERE invoice_id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':creditcard', PaymentGateway::METHOD_TYPE_CREDITCARD);
```

You should always use parameters because of security. It is insane to not use it in these days, because of [Sql Injection](http://php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: +1 And not just security, but also ease. Once you've made the switch to parameters, it's so easy to use them. And you don't have to think about how to escape or quote or otherwise preprocess values. You just tell MySQL: "Here is an int" or "here is a string" and the rest is taken care of. And it can actually result in better performance too!